# MySQL order by the highest score

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

I have two tables:

```
  CREATE TABLE `fl_poll` (
  `id_poll` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_player` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `position` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ip` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_anketa`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE `fl_player` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_team` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

And I would like to ask, is any solution how to select all players from table fl_player, count their score and order by top 3 players who have the highest score and others will be order by their lastname? For example I have six players:

table fl_player:

```
id     |     lastname    
------------------------
1             Smith           
2            Johnson          
3             Todd             
4             Dragon            
5             Bond             
6             Black
```

table fl_poll:

```
+-----------+-------+
| id_player | score |
+-----------+-------+
|         1 |     2 |
|         2 |     4 |
|         3 |     6 |
|         4 |     8 |
|         5 |    10 |
|         6 |    12 |
+-----------+-------+
```

And I wish result like this:

```
+-----------+----------------------------------------+
| id_player |                lastname                |
+-----------+----------------------------------------+
|         6 | Black <-- top 3 with highest score     |
|         5 | Bond                                   |
|         4 | Dragon                                 |
|         2 | Johnson <-- from now order by lastname |
|         1 | Smith                                  |
|         3 | Todd                                   |
+-----------+----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: One question, could a player have more than one entry in the poll table requiring summing?

Comment: Another question, what if there is a tie for third place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  SELECT   fl_poll.id_player, fl_player.lastname, fl_poll.score, 1 AS type
  FROM     fl_player
      JOIN fl_poll ON fl_poll.id_player = fl_player.id
  WHERE    fl_poll.score >= (
             SELECT MIN(score) FROM (
               SELECT score FROM fl_poll ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 3
             ) t
           )

UNION

  SELECT   fl_poll.id_player, fl_player.lastname, fl_poll.score, 2 AS type
  FROM     fl_player
      JOIN fl_poll ON fl_poll.id_player = fl_player.id
  WHERE    fl_poll.score < (
             SELECT MIN(score) FROM (
               SELECT score FROM fl_poll ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 3
             ) t
           )

ORDER BY CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN score END DESC, lastname
```

Comment: This has no `order by` on the results of the `union`.  MySQL does not guarantee the ordering of results from a `union`, so an `order by` is needed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff:  Ugh.  Good spot.  See my revision.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
SELECT s.id_player, n.lastname FROM fl_poll AS s INNER JOIN fl_player AS n ON n._id = s.id_player ORDER BY s.score DESC;
```

can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.  Join to a sub-select to get the top 3, order by their score in descending order.  The players not in the top 3 will not have a score, so their score from the top3 subselect will be NULL (because they did not match one of the top 3), and they will appear after the top 3.  They will simply be sorted in order by last_name.

```
SELECT po.id_player, lastname

FROM   fl_player pl

     LEFT JOIN 

(

SELECT pl.id, SUM(score) score

FROM   fl_player pl

       JOIN fl_poll po ON pl.id = po.id_player

GROUP BY pl.id

ORDER BY SUM(score) DESC

LIMIT 3

) as top3 on fl.id = top3.id

ORDER BY top3.score DESC, last_name
```

Use this if you want to include each player's score:

```
SELECT po.id_player, lastname, SUM(score) score

FROM   fl_player pl

       JOIN fl_poll po ON pl.id = po.id_player

     LEFT JOIN 

(

SELECT pl.id, SUM(score) score

FROM   fl_player pl

       JOIN fl_poll po ON pl.id = po.id_player

GROUP BY pl.id

ORDER BY SUM(score) DESC

LIMIT 3

) as top3 on fl.id = top3.id

GROUP BY pl.id

ORDER BY top3.score DESC, last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 2)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY username);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely dangerous (and wrong) to depend on `union` to return results in a particular order.

Here is an entirely different approach.  Create a list of the top three ids by score.  If the user is in that list, then order them by score.  Otherwise order them by name.

You can get the list by using `substring_index(group_concat( . . . ))`.  The rest is just setting up the `order by` clause to use this information:

```
select p.id_player, p.lastname
from fl_player p cross join
     (select substring_index(group_concat(id order by score desc), ',', 3) as ids
      from fl_player
     ) top3
order by find_in_set(id, top3.ids) > 0,
         (case when find_in_set(id, top3.ids) > 0 then score end) desc,
         name
```